# Are these controller specs good enough?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, functional-testing

I am new to testing controllers with RSpec. In my controller, I have these methods:

```
  def edit
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
    if @widget.present?
      @all_widgets = Widget.where(:id != @widget.id).select("id, title")
      wfs @widget.id
    else
      redirect_to widgets_url
    end
  end
```

and

```
  def wfs widget_id
    @all_features,
    @existing_features,
    @draft_features,
    @imported_features  = WidgetFeature.find_by_widget_id_group_by_status(widget_id)
  end
```

I have tested the method `WidgetFeature.find_by_widget_id_group_by_status(widget_id)` in the corresponding model.

Now, I don't know how to test the `edit` method and what to test. I know all about stubs, mocks and doubles. I am following the **Rails Test Prescriptions** and **the RSpec book**.
So, I am familiar with the terminology and the basics, however I am confused when to mock or make a factory for the data.

Also, how do I test that the *edit* method actually calls the *wfs* method?

**UPDATE:**
These are some specs I have written, that give 100% coverage (tested by SimpleCov).   Is this the best way to test the above methods.

```
  context " When #edit is called, it" do
    it "assigns @all_widgets & other variables if widget for given widget_id is present" do
      widget = Factory.create(:widget)
      get :edit, :id => widget.id
      assigns.each {|a| a.should be_kind_of(Array)}
      response.should be_success
      response.should render_template("edit")
    end
    it "redirects_to widgets_url if widget for given widget_id is not present" do
      widget = Widget.stub!(:find).with(12)
      get :edit, :id => 12
      response.should redirect_to(widgets_url)
      response.should be_redirect
    end
  end
```

Comments are welcome on how to improve the above specs

Answer (score 0):

You should mock WidgetFeature. In that way tests will be faster as it does not hit DB. And to check whether *edit* method is calling *wfs* method, you can use should_receive.

Comment: @leensan: I know it's asking too much of you or anyone. But can you provide a short snippet of how to do it. That'd be really helpful.

Comment: Instead of `Factory.create(:widget)`, you can say `mock_model(Widget)`.